# JsHelper::domReady function doesn't work !

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, helper

I'm using CakePHP to develop a website..

I'm using the latest jQuery library..
using JsHelper to do something like this:

```
$this->Js->domReady ( $this->Js->alert ('Page loaded !') );
```

but no JavaScript code was generated on the page !!
this is supposed to generate something similar to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){alert("Page loaded !");});
```

I'm really surprised !!
is it a problem with jQuery engine ?
does the same problem exist with other libraries ?

any help will be appreciated ...

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is the question?

Comment: I'm sorry...  
I included more details in the question...

Comment: As far as I am aware, jQuery doesn't have a PHP library? Can you please elaborate on on which PHP library you are using and where its documentation is? And maybe a little more on your usage of this library? The vague nature of this question is proving difficult to answer.

Comment: Just noticed the cakephp tag, looking at documentation now.

Comment: sorry again...

I didn't mention the cakephp in the question ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to make it like:

```
echo $this->Js->domReady ( $this->Js->alert ('Page loaded !') );
```

Although I use CakePHP as main framework in my development I am not using Js helper. I believe that Javascript need to stay aside. :)

Comment: thanx.. this is printing the correct code!  

but it is printing the code on the screen!!

Comment: oh I figured out how to do that...

now I'm doing: `$this->Html->scriptBlock ( $this->Js->domReady ( $this->Js->alert ( 'Page loaded!' ) ), array ( 'inline' => false ) );`

Answer (score 0):

Do you do:

```
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
```

The call above only constructs the JS code, it does not include it in the document.

Comment: yep. I'm doing that exactly before </body> in my layout.. I tried `event` function and it work perfectly! it generates the correct code for the `event` function but nothing for `domReady`...